# What's the BNF of doctrine for?

Tags: doctrine, bnf

It looks like a big mess,how does it work as reference?

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/dql-doctrine-query-language%3Abnf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's used as a reference by any human-being, actually ; but it might be useful if someone want to use some automatic tool that understands BNF ; for instance, some kind of code generator.

The advantage of BNF being that's it's a formal way to describe a language -- much more easier to understand than english, when you are a program.

For reference :

- [BNF = Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)
- [Software using BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form#Software_using_BNF)

---

**Edit after the comments :** Here's a quick example about the DQL / Object stuff :

Let's consider this portion of code, which is using the object-oriented API to write a query, execute it, and get the results *(hydrated as arrays -- prints out only the data, this way, when debugging)* :

```
$result = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('p.id, p.title, u.login')
            ->from('Ab_Model_Post p')
            ->innerJoin('p.User u')
            ->where('p.codeStatus = ?')
            ->orderBy('p.date desc')
            ->limit(2)
            ->execute(array('OK'), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
var_dump($result);
```

And here's the kind of output you'll get :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Septième post' (length=14)
      'User' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'login' => string 'user1' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Sixième post (draft=7)' (length=23)
      'User' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'login' => string 'user1' (length=5)
```

*Of course, this is considering the schema and models classes are OK -- and sorry for the example in french, I used a schema/model/database I set up some time ago for a demonstration of Doctrine, which was in french.*

Basically, the DB is for a blogging application, and, here, we :

- get some data from posts and the user who posted them
- for valid posts
- the most recents posts
- only two posts

Now, here's an equivalent, using what I meant by "DQL" as in "pseudo-SQL language" :

```
$result = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->query(<<<DQL
select p.id, p.title, u.login
from Ab_Model_Post as p, 
    p.User u
where p.codeStatus = ?
order by p.date desc
limit 2
DQL
    , array('OK'), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
var_dump($result);
```

No object-oriented API here *(well, to write the query, I mean)* : I only wrote that pseudo-SQL I was thinking about -- which is what the BNF describes, as far as I can tell.

And, of course, the output of the `var_dump` is exactly the same as the one I got before.

I hope this makes things a bit more clear :-)

Comment: Is the BNF for all possible cases of **sql** generated by doctrine?

Comment: That BNF is for the DQL language -- i.e. the "pseudo-SQL" language that Doctrine understand ; and not what it generates.

Comment: But I don't find the most used DQL like `leftJoin`,`create` and so on.

Comment: About left joins, it is present in `join_spec` ;;; about create : are you sure there is a create instruction in DQL ? To create tables, Doctrine uses it's DB Abstraction Layer (see http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/technology:architecture:doctrine-dbal ), and you don't write DQL.

Comment: Isn't it used here:Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('Network n')
    ->leftJoin('n.Members u')
    ->where('n.slug = ?');

?

Comment: The "DQL" that's described by the BNF is the "pseudo-SQL" language ; not the Classes/Objects -- yeah, I admit that http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/dql-doctrine-query-language is really not making things clear and using "DQL" for both the "looking like a subset of SQL" and the classes/methods :-(

Comment: I'm still confused,can you elaborate a little on what you mean by "pseudo-SQL"?

Comment: @user198729 : I just edited my answer with a quick example, as a demonstration that illustrates what I was thinking about. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

It's Backus–Naur Form, a method of describing context free grammars. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).